# I have drunken the water / I have drunk the water

Tags: grammar, tenses, past-tense

Assume that it is impossible to rephrase. I am inclined to believe drunk is correct, but I need another opinion.

Comment: Any dictionary can tell you the past simple and past participle of "drink".  Where have you searched?

Comment: This question is not simply about the past tense of drink, but rather what should be used in this very specific sentence. "I have drank the water" is clearly wrong.

Comment: A past participle must be used in the perfect tenses, the present perfect in this case.

Comment: I was just unsure whether "drunken" is completely unviable under any circumstances, or if it could ever be used.

Comment: *Drink, drank, drunk; sink, sank, sunk; swim, swam, swum; sing, sang, sung; ring, rang, rung; etc.*

Answer (score 2):

The past participle is "drunk". "Drunken" is an adjective, its use as the past participle is obsolete.

Thus

> I have drunk the water, while my drunken father has drunk another beer.

Next time you may prefer to check out a [dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/) to avoid people's angry comments.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Though the origin of both words is the same, the usage is different.

**drunk** is the p.p. of drink, and you're right to use it in your example:

> I have drunk the water

**drunken** is an adjective meaning that someone has drunk alcohol more than he can handle: (similar to another usage of *drunk*):

> He's really drunk.
>
> They are a bunch of drunken idiots.

Comment: The adjective drunken can be used only  before a noun. No predicative use.http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/drunken?q=drunken